# Facebook login showing not defined index: email only for gmail users

Tags: facebook, authentication, gmail

I've made App and facebook login for my site. But I've tested it and it works for another type of mail. I tried now with gmail and it's showing:
`ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined index: email`

My method for that is:

```html
 public function action_fbLogin(){
      
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId'  => 'MyAppId',
            'secret' => 'MySecret',
        ));

        $user = $facebook->getUser();
        if ($user) {

            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me', array('fields' => 'id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture')); 
         
            $user_id = Model_UserFunctions::checkIfUserExist($user_profile['email']); 
            if($user_id > 0)
            {
                
                Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                    'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                    'user_id' => $user_id,
                    'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'first_name' =>  $user_profile['first_name'],
                    'last_name' =>  $user_profile['last_name'],
                ));
                
             
                $this->redirect('profile');
                exit;
            }
            $values = array(
                    'email' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'username' => $user_profile['email'],
                    'password' => '12345678'
                );
            $user = ORM::factory ( 'User' );
            $user->values($values);
            try
            {
                if($user->save()){
                    $user_new_id = $user->as_array();
                    $user_new_id = $user_new_id['id'];
                    Session::instance()->set('user', array(
                            'fb_id' => $user_profile['id'],
                            'user_id' => $user_new_id,
                            'pic' => $user_profile['picture'],
                            'email' => $user_profile['email'], 
                            'first_name' => $user_profile['first_name'],
                            'last_name' => $user_profile['last_name'],
                        ));
                    
                    $this->redirect('profile');
                }


            }
            catch (ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
            {
                $result = $e->errors('models');
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($result);
                exit;
            }


        }
        else 
        {
            
            $this->redirect($facebook->getLoginUrl(array('id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture'))); 
        }
        exit;
    
    }
```

Are there other things that I should add to my code for gmail users? Thank you in advance!

Edited: my method for logut is:

```html
 public  function action_logout(){
        Session::instance()->delete('user');
        $this->redirect('/');
    }
```

Maybe problem is that it doesn't logout. I'm not sure. It shows me the same user data although I'm logged with different user.

Comment: This has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with the fact that it is a gmail address. What it does have to do with, is has the user granted your app permission to read their email, whether their email is confirmed, and in some edge cases privacy settings.

Comment: Yes, I've done this. But I have no explanation it's not working only for gmail. It's working for other types of mail. I think it could be because there is Google + Login button and maybe it should be used for gmail users, is this true?

Comment: No, that is of course not true. There is not connection whatsoever between the Facebook login and the Google+ login; they don’t know of each other, and they don’t care. I use a gmail address myself on Facebook, and that can be retrieved perfectly fine via API. You _think_ it is only not working for gmail addresses, but that is just a coincidence.

Comment: But when I use another type of mail, I get logged when var_dump($user_profile) from my code, I could see email address. But when I try to log with my gmail address, it is undefined and throws notice.

Comment: Now I saw that when I logout from first account and log with another account, I'm still in first account. I also tried to clean history but the same. My code is from the code in question. Do you see any mistakes? :)